# Porting pre-trained keras models and run them on IPU

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, ipu

I am trying to port two pre-trained keras models into the IPU machine. I managed to load and run them using IPUstrategy.scope but I dont know if i am doing it the right way. I have my pre-trained models in .h5 file format.
I load them this way:

```
def first_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./model1.h5")
return model
```

After searching your ipu.keras.models.py file I couldn't find any load methods to load my pre-trained models, and this is why i used tf.keras.models.load_model().

Then i use this code to run:

```
cfg=ipu.utils.create_ipu_config()
cfg=ipu.utils.auto_select_ipus(cfg, 1)
ipu.utils.configure_ipu_system(cfg)
ipu.utils.move_variable_initialization_to_cpu()

strategy = ipu.ipu_strategy.IPUStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    model = first_model()

    print('compile attempt\n')
    model.compile("sgd", "categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
    print('compilation completed\n')
    
    print('running attempt\n')
    res = model.predict(input_img)[0]
    print('run completed\n')
```

you can see the output here:[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGd46.png)

So i have some difficulties to understand how and if the system is working properly.
Basically the model.compile wont compile my model but when i use model.predict then the system first compiles and then is running. Why is that happening? Is there another way to run pre-trained keras models on an IPU chip?

Another question I have is if its possible to load a pre-trained keras model inside an ipu.keras.model and then use model.fit/evaluate to further train and evaluate it and then save it for future use?

One last question I have is about the compilation part of the graph. Is there a way to avoid recompilation of the graph every time i use the model.predict() in a different strategy.scope()?

I use tensorflow2.1.2 wheel

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add some context, the Graphcore TensorFlow wheel includes a port of Keras for the IPU, available as `tensorflow.python.ipu.keras`. You can access the API documentation for IPU Keras at [this link](https://docs.graphcore.ai/projects/tensorflow-user-guide/en/latest/api.html#module-tensorflow.python.ipu.keras). This module contains IPU-specific optimised replacement for TensorFlow [Keras classes](https://docs.graphcore.ai/projects/tensorflow-user-guide/en/latest/targetting_tf2.html#keras) `Model` and `Sequential`, plus more high-performance, multi-IPU classes e.g. `PipelineModel` and `PipelineSequential`.

As per your specific issue, you are right when you mention that there are no IPU-specific ways to load pre-trained Keras models at present. I would encourage you, as you appear to have access to IPUs, to reach out to Graphcore Support. When doing so, please attach your pre-trained Keras model `model1.h5` and a self-contained reproducer of your code.

Switching topic to the recompilation question: using an executable cache prevents recompilation, you can set that up with environmental variable `TF_POPLAR_FLAGS='--executable_cache_path=./cache'`. I'd also recommend to take a look into the following resources:

- this [tutorial](https://github.com/graphcore/examples/tree/master/tutorials/tensorflow2/recompilation) gathers several considerations around recompilation and how to avoid it when using TensorFlow2 on the IPU.
- Graphcore TensorFlow documentation [here](https://docs.graphcore.ai/projects/tensorflow-user-guide/en/latest/compiling.html#compiling-and-pre-compiling-executables) explains how to use the pre-compile mode on the IPU.